# Cant understand a syntax in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I know its a really stupid question, but can anyone help me understanding these lines:

```
dim dmnth = array()
Redim dmnth(Rs_emp_count + 1, Rs_proj_count + 1, total_days + 1)
dmnth(emp_cnt, prj_cnt, 0) = pname & " (" & pid & ")"
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Redim in your case will resize your array as a 3 dimensional one with the 3 values supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dim dmnth = array()`; this sets `dmth` to the return value of the function `array()`; whatever that is. It is an unnecessary step in your program; unless `array()` does something useful aside from returning a value back.

`Redim dmnth(Rs_emp_count + 1, Rs_proj_count + 1, total_days + 1)`; this trashes the contents of `dmth`; replacing `dmnth` with a 3D array with sizes, for each dimension respectively, `Rs_emp_count + 1`, `Rs_proj_count + 1` and `total_days + 1`. All elements are cleared.

`dmnth(emp_cnt, prj_cnt, 0) = pname & " (" & pid & ")"` assigns `pname & " (" & pid & ")"` to the `(emp_cnt, prj_cnt, 0)` element of the array. Remember that arrays in VBScript are zero based; i.e. (0, 0, 0) is a valid element.

Answer (score 2):

- `dim dmnth = array()`

  This is an invalid statement. In VBScript you can't declare a variable and initialize it with a value in a single statement. It probably should be

  ```
  Dim dmnth
  dmnth = Array()
  ```

  or shorter

  ```
  Dim dmnth : dmnth = Array()
  ```

  which declares a variable `dmnth` and initializes the variable with an empty array. This is, however, only useful when you want to create an empty 1-dimensional array that will grow dynamically while preserving its values (which could also be achieved via `ReDim arr(-1)`). Since your array has 3 dimensions, this initialization is pointless. The command below would suffice for both declaration and initialization.
- `Redim dmnth(Rs_emp_count + 1, Rs_proj_count + 1, total_days + 1)`

  If `dmnth` already has been declared, this resizes the variable to a 3-dimensional array with the upper bounds `Rs_emp_count + 1` in the 1<sup>st</sup> dimension, `Rs_proj_count + 1` in the 2<sup>nd</sup> dimension, and `total_days + 1` in the 3<sup>rd</sup> dimension. Any content of the array will be discarded. If `dmnth` hasn't been declared, it's declared and initialized as a 3-dimensional array with the given upper bounds.
- `dmnth(emp_cnt, prj_cnt, 0) = pname & " (" & pid & ")"`

  This puts a string constructed from `pname` and `pid` into the array field at position `emp_cnt`, `prj_cnt`, `0`.

Answer (score 0):

First the dmnth is declared to be an array.
Then it is redeclared as a 3 dimensional array.
Then the Emp_cnt, Prj_Cnt, 0th entry is set to be pname & " (" & pid & ")"